# What is the correct name for a value to be used when an invalid value is given

Tags: single-word-requests

“**default value**” if often used to mean “The value to use when **no value** has been given” (see: [Is "default" used for "a value used when nothing has been explicitly set" outside of IT world?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94367/is-default-used-for-a-value-used-when-nothing-has-been-explicitly-set-outsid))

I think there's a similar word to mean "The value to use when **an invalid value** has been given"

Notice the subtle but important difference: not given ↔ given but not valid

I think it may be the “fault value”, but as I'm not finding any reference to it's use, I'm dubious about it.

Clarification:

It would be the right word to use in the following process description:

> Return x if x is in the range (BEGIN, END) or the
> <MISSING_WORD> value if not

Here “default value” is not correct because the value to be returned in this case is not necessarily one to be used. It might perfectly be a value that indicates that an erroneous input was given. And then, it might also be a value to be used, thus discarding the invalid input. In both cases “<MISSING_WORD> value” must be correct.

Comment: There is no *correct* name for that, you'll have to choose a suitable word and use it.  Personally I think you are overthinking this and that *default* is just fine, it denotes the value to be used when the user doesn't provide a valid input, whether by omitting one or by providing a wonky one.

Comment: You seem to be attempting to make a distinction without a difference: a default value is the value to which a program reverts (defaults) upon failure (either by error or omission.)

Comment: @Greybeard not really, see the clarification.

Comment: Error flag value.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty “Yes but” this would only cover one case, it wouldn't be valid if the value to be returned is the value to be actually used.

Comment: Oh, and on further looking at this I realise that the naming of things, including the naming of program things, is explicitly off-topic on this site.  If I could VTC I would.

Comment: You don't seem clear what you want. If there is an invalid value, error, or exception in your function, you may want to return an error flag that indicates there was an error and signals to the caller not to proceed any further; or you may want to return a default value that can be used instead of the value that you failed to calculate. These are two different cases: in the first you indicate an error, in the second you do not. What happens afterwards is completely different. You shouldn't confuse the two cases.

Comment: 'Corrected value' seems clear.

Comment: **1.** If you mean that the range is 1 to 9 and if 0.5, or e.g. ‘H’, is entered then “1” should be used, then “1” is the default value. -- **2.** If you mean that the range is 1 to 9 and nothing is entered, and the next operation is attempted, then “1” should be used, then “1” is still the default value. -- **3.** If you mean that the range is 1 to 9 and nothing, or e.g. ‘H’, is entered, and the next operation is attempted, and “ERROR!” (or any other form of words) is printed, then “ERROR!” (etc.) is an/the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The term that I've sometimes seen and used is "fallback value".

This is derived from the following definition as in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/fallback)

> An alternative plan that may be used in an emergency.

Comment: Nice, I like it. Not the word I was looking for, but a good option to use 

Answer (score -1):

Could it be «on-error»? The “on-error value” ?

In this case the example given would say:

> Return x if x is in the range (BEGIN, END) or **the on-error
> value if not**

Please comment whether you think this could be appropriate.

Comment: Picture me sticking two fingers down my throat at this suggestion!  But tell us one more thing - is the *on-error value* the same as the *no-value value*?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark () Certainly  not. Taking as example a weather station in southern Spain, the default value (_no-value value_) might be `SUNNY` while the _on-error value_ might be `ERROR_DETECTED`.

Comment: Avoid answering questions by asking another. Asking for comment is not an answer..